# XPath validation rules for XML

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-validation, xpath-2.0

I have the following XML -

```
<root>
  <CUSTOMER_ID>0010059863</CUSTOMER_ID>
  <PO_NUMBER>6873w/PO_NUMBER>
  <VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER>0038447</VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER>
</root>
```

I need to create a Xpath which should satisfy the following -

1. Customer ID length should be from 1 up to 10. Should not be empty string and it should always present in the XML.
2. PO_NUMBER length should be from 1 up to 20. PO_NUMBER can be blank or not even present in the XML. But it must have a value if it is the only one there and no VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER.
3. VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER length should be from 1 up to 10. VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER can be blank or not even present in the XML. But it must have a value if it is the only one there and no PO_NUMBER.
4. At least one of PO_NUMBER or VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER should be present in the XML. They both can be present in the XML as well.
5. We must need to check the field lengths are met.
6. The Vendor number and PO_number can be there in XML as blank tag.

I have written the following- could anyone of you please review this and let me know if there is any other option than this?

`boolean(//CUSTOMER_ID) and boolean(//VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER) and count(//PO_NUMBER)=0 and string-length(//VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER)<=10 and //VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER!="" and string-length(//CUSTOMER_ID)<=10 and //CUSTOMER_ID!=""  or boolean(//CUSTOMER_ID) and boolean(//PO_NUMBER) and count(//VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER)=0 and string-length(//PO_NUMBER)<=10 and //PO_NUMBER!="" and string-length(//CUSTOMER_ID)<=10 and //CUSTOMER_ID!="" or (boolean(//CUSTOMER_ID) and boolean(//VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER) and boolean(//PO_NUMBER) and string-length(//VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER)<=10 and //VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER!="" and string-length(//CUSTOMER_ID)<=10 and //CUSTOMER_ID!="" and  string-length(//PO_NUMBER)<=20) or (boolean(//CUSTOMER_ID) and boolean(//VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER) and boolean(//PO_NUMBER) and string-length(//PO_NUMBER)<=20 and //PO_NUMBER!="" and string-length(//CUSTOMER_ID)<=10 and //CUSTOMER_ID!="" and  string-length(//VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER)<=10)`

Comment: If you want people to read and comment on this code, please do us the courtesy of adding some layout (indentation) to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task for Schematron e.g. to give you a start:

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt3">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="root">
          <report test="CUSTOMER_ID">root element has CUSTOMER_ID child.</report>
          <report test="PO_NUMBER | VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER">At least one of PO_NUMBER or VENDOR_ORDER_NUMBER should be present in the XML.</report>
        </rule>
        <rule context="root/CUSTOMER_ID">
          <report test="string-length() = (1 to 10)">Length of CUSTOMER_ID is between 1 and 10.</report>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

I haven't spelled out all the rules and I am not sure they are all consistent (with some requiring a certain string length and other allowing empty values).